# Login My User name share point its showing System Login Name

Tags: sharepoint-2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mdjx.png)I am working with Sharepoint 2013, when logging in My Username (Username) and password (Password) its login successfully, after Login the screen right hand side its shows e system login Name like "System/Account" and Permission level also taken System Login only, not for my Login ID

Important Note : I don't have Admin access to check for share point server.

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you're asking, and moreover I am not sure this is about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your account may be a farm admin account or an app pool account.